# External script makes Wordpress pages black

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

So I am running into a problem with WordPress, and I have tried anything in my (beginners) develop skills to try and tackle this problem, but so far no luck so I'm trying it on here.

So I'm building this website for an online radio station, that wants to post their episodes and live streams on Mixcloud but also want to publish them on to there (new) website. Via customization in the theme that I am using, I managed to pull a custom field within a Wordpress Post as parameter to trigger the Mixcloud Footer Widget.

And here starts the problem...

The footer widget of Mixcloud needs to be on the whole site so it continues playing while looking throughout the website. Since I have added the scrips of Mixcloud, the first request of the website will load the Wordpress page itself, and the footer, also the widget receives the correct parameter/custom field if you click on the image. So that part is working perfectly.

But when I click on another link, the homepage, for example, the footer widget stays loaded and keeps playing (which it should!) but the rest of the site isn't loading or showing properly. I do see in the source code that the HTML part of the website does load, but it shows as a white page for some reason. This is the script from Mixcloud that I'm using:

`<script src="//widget.mixcloud.com/media/js/widgetApi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//widget.mixcloud.com/media/js/footerWidgetApi.js" async>
            {"feed": "/itmotr-radio/"}
        </script>`

I have been told that the script might load before the page itself, but I don't think that's the reason why the pages aren't showing correctly, because like I mentioned before, the source code is fully there, but it isn't showing correctly.

**Things I have tried**
- Using a plugin to add the scripts in the footer
- Placing the script into the footer.php of the theme
- Placing the script into the function.php of the theme
- Adding tags to the script so the loading will be done after the whole site is loaded.

If I remove the script, the pages show up as normal, but then I lose full functionality of the thing that I want to accomplish.

Does someone know how to tackle this problem?
It will help me a lot :)

Best regards,
Casper 

------------
using Salient theme
using the newest version of WordPress
using Brackets and FileZilla and Brackets to edit and upload my custom files

Comment: Just to confirm when you click another link to load a page is that new page loaded using javascript? My initial suggestion would be to check if the request for the new pages actually happens. Use your browser to see if the request happens -> F12 -> Network Tab

Comment: @tfcmad I don't think the new page is loaded via Javascript (sorry I'm quit new to this). I do notice in the Network Tab, that when I click to another page, it will send and receive some things, but not all of them. If I go from shows to the homepage it will load only 2.8MB of resources, and when I fully reload the homepage it will 6.4MB of resources, so there is missing quite a lot of data. Any ideas on how to fix this?